# C'est du beau travail / C'est du bon travail

Tags: usage, adjectifs

Je voudrais savoir quand on doit utiliser une expression et quand on doit l'autre expression, car je ne saurais pas dire la différence. La seule chose que je sais c'est que « C'est du beau travail » peut avoir un sens ironique, en se référant à avoir fait quelque chose avec un résultat catastrophique.

J'aimerais savoir aussi si l'expression « C'est du bon travail » est correcte.
La même chose vaut pour: « C'était un bon match » / « C'etait un beau match ».
Je ne réussis pas à voir la différence.

Comment: This isn’t relevant to the way I think you’re using the phrases (i.e., to congratulate someone for doing a good job), but in the context of saying “That’s a sweet job/gig **if** you can get it,” I think I’d probably use “bon” instead of “beau” (“C’est du/un bon travail/boulot **si** … tu l'obtiens… tu peux le trouver,” for example), but I’m not sure why (or even if it would be correct).

Comment: Le ton et le contexte restent importants pour comprendre le sens des expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si *du* peut être employé avec ironie, *un* ne peut pas l'être :

> C'est *un* beau travail
>   C'est *un* bon match

... n'ont pas de sens ironique.

- *Un* et *du* ne portent pas les mêmes possibilités d'intonation
- De même *beau* et *bon* ne sont pas interchangeables :

C'est un *bon* match, car le score est nul, on a mal joué sans perdre de point au classement face à un adversaire plus fort (le match est *bon* pour nous, pour l'avenir du club)

C'est un *beau* match émaillé de buts spectaculaires, avec un jeu collectif sans faille, même si on a perdu d'un point, le spectacle était au rendez-vous (tout le monde a apprécié la qualité [et même la beauté des actions] du jeu).

Pour le travail, il en va de même, ce sont les définitions de *beau* (travail de qualité et esthétique) et *bon* (travail qui correspond parfaitement à ce qui a été demandé) qui font la différence, avec :

> - ***un*** beau/bon travail : on apprécie l'œuvre effectué,
> - ***du*** beau/bon travail : on qualifie ce que l'on voit, et donc on peut le formuler avec une intonation ironique.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la première section. Serait-il possible d'écrire des des phrases, où est-ce trop demander ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - J'ai réorganisé ma réponse.

Comment: Dans le sens où la plupart des gens l'entendent, un bon match est un match bien joué, pas forcément impressionant mais bien joué... AMHA.

Comment: @NathanCoustenoble -- *Beau* et *bon* ont une 'partie commune' où ils peuvent être inter-changés, selon l'enthousiasme ou le club du supporter. De plus le vocabulaire sportif n'est pas toujours en accord avec celui de l'Académie, mais la différence entre la *beauté* et la *bonté* demeure, l'emploi de l'un ou de l'autre pour qualifier une situation 'moyenne' dénote l'état d'esprit du locuteur.

Answer (score 6):

Les deux mots sont plutôt interchangeables, mais tu peux y voir une nuance :

> C'est du beau travail

Se rapporte plus à un travail **impressionnant**, qui attire l'attention.

> C'est du bon travail

Attire l'attention sur la **qualité** du travail plus que sur le côté spectaculaire de ce travail.

Néanmoins, personne ne t'en voudra d'interchanger les deux mots, puisque la différence réside dans une nuance.

Answer (score 1):

Les 2 sont des compliments:

*C'est du bon travail* = compliment sur la qualité du travail effectué (bien fait). On peut faire du bon travail, mais de manière *rustre*, *pataude*.

*C'est du beau travail* = compliment à connotation esthétique = *c'est élégant, cela a de l'allure*, etc. Nettement plus subjectif. En général, c'est aussi du *bon* travail.

*C'est du beau !*  Sens ironique qui signifie, qu'on est dans une situation tout à fait *inapropriée* :

- *tu as fait n'importe quoi* (volontairement ou non);
- *tu as tout cassé* (une voiture, ...);
- *tu as provoqué une (petite) catastrophe (tu as renversé le pot de peinture, la bassine, ...)*